# how to delete unused connections in an SSIS package deployed as an SQL Server Agent job step?

Tags: ssis, ssms, sql-server-agent

I have an SSIS package deployed to an SQL Server by Project deployment model.

When I configure to use that package as a job step, I see that there are other connections that this package does not use at all (they are all project-scope connections). I tried to look in the SSMS as well as to google but got no luck to find a way to remove these unused connections. Please advise. I can not remove these project-scope connections because they are used by some other packages in the SSIS project.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy with the project deployment model, you inherit those connection managers. If you don't want them in your package, you could:

1. Put your package in another project;
2. Convert the project connection managers to package-scope for the other packages.

But you can't have your package as part of a project, without the connection managers of that project.